# Pyspark best practice for filtering with multiple and conditions

Tags: filter, pyspark

Which is **best practice** and **leads to better performance**. Let us assume we have the following dataframe (just a small toy example).

```
values = [
  (1, 2, 3, 'united_states'),
  (2, 5, 8, 'brazil'),
  (3, 7, 7, 'france'),
  (4, 1, 1, 'france'),
  (5, 2, 3, 'brazil'),
]

columns = ['id', 'column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']

df = spark.createDataFrame(values, columns)

# output
+---+--------+--------+-------------+
| id|column_1|column_2|     column_3|
+---+--------+--------+-------------+
|  1|       2|       3|united_states|
|  2|       5|       8|       brazil|
|  3|       7|       7|       france|
|  4|       1|       1|       france|
|  5|       2|       3|       brazil|
+---+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Imagine I want to determine all entries where `(df.id < 5) & (df.column_3 == 'brazil') & (df.column_2 < 8)`. I can think of two ways to get the filtered dataframe.

```
# method 1
df_filtered = df.filter((df.id < 5) & (df.column_3 == 'brazil') & (df.column_2 < 8))

# method 2
df_filtered = df\
    .filter(df.id < 5)\
    .filter(df.column_3 == 'brazil')\
    .filter(df.column_2 < 8)
```

> Question: For me the first method has the advantage that everything is in one
>   single filter call. But the second method seems to longer but easiert
>   to comprehend. So here is my qustion which of the following methods is
>   considered **best practice** and which is **better performing**?

Edit: As proposed in the comments. I tested the runtime. And it seems that method_2 seems to perform better in many cases.

Comment: you can use `%timeit` to check yourself.. ?

Comment: @anky Thank you for your comment it seems that the second method performs better.

Comment: Both methods have the same execution plan. (`df_filtered.explain()`). There is no difference under the hood. In other words, both methods have identical performance.